# Rendering a view in express.Router()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to render EJS in a file that uses `express.Router()`, but I don't know how I would do that, since something like `router.set('view engine', 'ejs')` doesn't exist. How would I render my view?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set view engine to express object.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Then in route file you can render ejs template like this.

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/show_url', (req, res)=>{
    let data = {} //some data if have any
    res.render(ejs_template_file, {data})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you should set the view engine through app.use('view engine', 'ejs') and then within a route render something like res.render('view_file')

Comment: When I try to do that, it sets the views directory in the root folder, so it looks for index.ejs in /views, not where I want it to be.